# How to revert markAsPending() in Angular 2 form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using `form.markAsPending()` to show a loading spinner while the form is submitting data and I would like to `markAsNOTPending()` as soon as it completes, something like:

```
updateProfile(): void {
  this.updateProfileForm.markAsPending(); // <------- SET AS PENDING
  const formData = {
    username: this.updateProfileForm.value.username,
    email: this.updateProfileForm.value.email
  };

  this.us.editProfile(formData)
    .first()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.updateProfileForm.markAsNOTPending(); // <------- SET AS NOT PENDING
      },
      err => {
        this.updateProfileForm.setErrors({
          formError: true
        });
      }
    );
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `markAsPending()` is made for that, it is a state that describe that a `Validator` is validating and not yet finished. You can check the [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4799) for the implementation that gives more explanation.

Comment: Ok thanks, so you would rather use a variable to keep track of that?

Comment: Yes or you get the reference of the spinner with `@ViewChild`, show it before doing the update and hide it when you have the result

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just for info I managed to make it work with `.markAsPending()` by setting `this.updateProfileForm.setErrors({})` or by setting specific errors with the same method in the case I get some errors from the backend.

Answer (score -1):

I would set errors instead. Like the example below:

```
this.updateProfileForm.setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

and to remove it I would do this

```
this.updateProfileForm.setErrors(null);
```